# Cannot use operator ^ on a vector value

Tags: matlab, vector

```
function[df] = getDiscountFactor(t,T,r,i)
y=getYearFraction(t,T);
a=r(i,1)
df=1/((1+a)^y);
end
```

This is my code, thing is that y cannot do the (1+a)^y operation because it says it's a vector, but it is only a vector value r(i,1). When I call it in command line it prints a as 0.03 and then it shows this error

```
a =

    0.0300

Error using  ^ 
Inputs must be a scalar and a square
matrix.
To compute elementwise POWER, use
POWER (.^) instead.
```

If i use .^ operator problem is solved but df gets into a vector and I need it to be a single number.

Comment: Either place an answer on your question and mark it as accepted, or accept the answer that was written below, or delete your question.

Answer (score 0):

You've checked the first input to see that it's a scalar, so that presumably means the other input, `y`, is not a square matrix. If you check what `y` is too, you will probably see what's gone wrong.

And if not, does matlab have a function that tells you what type matlab thinks an object is? Run that on `a` and on `y`. Or to be extra pedantic, run that on `1+a`. That should clear things up.